# get more input from one command (discord.py)

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make an embed system that asks multiple questions and then put them together and send the embed with all the info given, but I can't figure out how to get multiple inputs in one command.

[image: this image maybe can help understanding my question]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I understand from your question, you're only checking for one possible input with `m.content == "hello"`. You can either remove it or add an `in` statement. Do view the revised code below.

```py
@commands.command()
async def greet(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Say hello!")

    def check(m):
        return m.channel == channel # only check the channel
        # alternatively,
        # return m.content.lower() in ["hello", "hey", "hi"] and m.channel == channel

    msg = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
    await ctx.send(f"Hello {msg.author}!")
```

[image: Expected command output]

---

In the case of the newly edited question, you can access the [`discord.Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message) class from the `msg` variable. For example, you can access the [`message.content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message.content). Do view the code snippet below.

```py
@commands.command()
async def test(ctx):
    def check(m):
        return m.channel == ctx.channel and m.author == ctx.author
        # return message if sent in current channel and author is command author

    em = discord.Embed()

    await ctx.send("Title:")
    msg = await bot.wait_for("message",check=check)
    em.title = msg.content

    # in this case, you can continue to use the same check function
    await ctx.send("Description:")
    msg = await bot.wait_for("message",check=check)
    em.description = msg.content

    await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

[image: above code in the works]

Comment: I added an image that may help you understand my question.

Comment: @monzzs do view my revised answer, thanks

Comment: it works, thanks a lot man!